# Ubuntu freezes upon shutdown or closing of laptop, makes me force reboot with power button

Tags: freeze

Whenever I sleep, shutdown, or even close the lid of my laptop, ubuntu freezes and I must manually restart with the power button. This started about a month or two ago.

I dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 11.
6.2.0-33-generic
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Dell: Precision 7560

Graphics Cards:
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104GLM [RTX A3000 Mobile] (rev a1)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Firstly, please ensure that in the BIOS/UEFI that Secure Boot is disabled and that UEFI is enabled. Also make sure that Windows Fast Start is disabled in Windows.

Comment: Use the `free` command to show how much RAM and swap you have. Hibernation require a RAM-sized, contiguous swap file (or a swap partition, but that's usually done at installation time). Read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.